# Intellij IDEA Ultimate android layout preview not working waiting for build finish

Tags: java, android, android-layout, intellij-idea

> IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-182.4892.20, built
>   on October 16, 2018 Licensed to IntelliJ IDEA Evaluator Expiration
>   date: November 27, 2018 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b19 x86_64 JVM:
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o macOS 10.13.6

I tried several ways.

- Refresh all gradle projects (in the right and top pannel)
- clean and rebuild
- invalidate and restart the IDEA

But it does not work.

And I noticed that:

- Android Studio alone: work
- IDEA alone: work
- Android Studio and IDEA both running: none of them work

I could build and run the project successfully but how to fix this?

[image: Waiting for build to finish]

Comment: try deleting `libs` folder inside `app`. maybe libs need to be refreshed, (Not sure)

Comment: thanks, I have already fixed it. There seems to be no need to delete *libs*.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: @JohnSardinha kindly see the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply solved it by choosing Sync Project with Gradle Files. 
This will trigger a Gradle re-import and a build.

One can find it using Find Action shortcut Ctrl + Shift + A and choose "Sync project With Gradle Files"

[image: How to find the action]
[image: The result]

Comment: But in question you said its not working for you `I tried several ways. >Refresh all gradle projects (in the right and top panel)` ?

Comment: @AliAhmed yes, I clicked the first button in the right pannel which seems like a circle and shows "Refresh All Gradle Files" when the mouse is hanging on it.

Sorry for the misunderstanding for the previous question description. Anyway, it works now

Comment: Can confirm, this solution works. I still can't understand why though

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the options from Nexus 4/version/Theme in the intellij.

[image]